# foundation section vertical tabs title width

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to change width of section vertical tabs title. My code:

```
<div class="section-container vertical-tabs" data-section="vertical-tabs">
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     <section id ="@item.Id">
         <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">@item.Description</a></p>
         <div class="content" data-section-content>
            <p>@(new HtmlString(item.IntroductoryText))</p>
         </div>
      </section>
  }
```

result :

title width is too small... there is some way to change it ?

Comment: does setting the width with css not change it?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.title{
    width:100px; /*Or whatever you want it to be*/
}
```